# Improve performance on SQL update from table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm running a query like the following

```
update foo f set type=b.type from bar b where f.bar_id = b.id;
```

Each of these tables has several million rows. What I find strange is doing an analyze on this query shows that it runs 2 table scans, rather than using the fact that it's joining on `bar`s primary key.

Any thoughts on how to make it use the index or otherwise increase the speed?

Comment: how many records will be updated as % of all records in `foo`?  and how many bar records will be used in this update?

Comment: All records are being updated in foo - (it's actually a backfill following a data denormalization). Few million rows in both tables. Specifically in this schema, bars actually own foos, so all the bars will probably be used.

Comment: So why do you think full read is not the most optimal way for this operation?

Comment: It just seems that it is much slower than it should be. Several hours with no result. (All stats on the machine [cpu,mem,disk i/o] seem okay)

Comment: Using an index on `foo` would just require more I/O for no benefit in this case, since you're reading the whole table. It may be useful for `bar` but it depends on ... well, all sorts of things. Please show the actual `EXPLAIN` output, don't just describe it. If you're feeling paranoid about exposing table names, use http://explain.depesz.com/ 's "anonymize plan" option.

Comment: @KurtSpindler _index_ `id` fields on both _tables_

Comment: also check what your memory and IO usage look like while query is running

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does a poor job of costing this kind of statement.  The problem is that it costs them pretty much as if it were just a select query, ignoring the fact that it now has to visit each qualifying row of `foo` to make the change to it.  So if it chooses a query path which returns the rows of `foo` out of physical order, which is pretty much all query paths other than:

```
nested loop
    seq scan on foo
    index scan on bar
```

then it just going to jump all over tarnation trying to update the rows of `foo` out of order.

If it does choose the above plan, now it is jumping all over `bar` reading that out of order.  But jumping all over dirtying pages is usually much worse than jumping all over reading pages without dirtying them.

Your best bet is probably just to recreate `foo2` using a CREATE TABLE...AS SELECT...
and then doing a rename.  That can be painful if there are a lot of foreign key constraints and views referencing `foo`.

If you have the RAM, you could try to crank up work_mem to the point where you get single-pass plan:

```
hash join
    seq scan on foo
    hash
        seq scan on bar
```

But if it decides it needs to do it in multiple passes because it won't fit in memory, then things go south in a hurry as you are back to jumping around randomly.  Worse, PostgreSQL is no help at all in planning this, and you are just as likely to get

```
hash join
    seq scan on bar
    hash
        seq scan on foo
```

Which is a horrible plan.

Answer (score 0):

Take in account transaction log pressure in your case. May be you can split transaction into several ones with 50k rows in each?

Also, in case of update >1m rows I recommend you to alter all indexes except covers WHERE clause to INACTIVE state before UPDATE.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "*transaction log pressure*"? Postgres does not use the term "transaction log".

Comment: Very long transactions grow up tran.log dramatically. It means massive I/O when commit/rollback occured. If you split transactions into small ones, you can win in time manner.

Comment: Are you aware that Postgres does *not* have a thing called "transaction log" which could be "filled up"? Your statement might be true for SQL Server, but for many other DBMS (including Postgres and Oracle) doing fewer large transactions is almost always faster than many small transactions.

Comment: You're quite right. Sorry, I did take MSSQL into account when answer, sorry. Tag "sql" seems like unversal mistake for me :)

Comment: Questions related to MS SQL Server are (should be) tagged with `sql-server`